# Changes on a variable that disappears

Tags: java, variables

I'm making a little java game, and I have to use a double named battery.
It is decreased regularly, and, sometimes increased. Here is my method :

```
public void agirBatterie() {
    for(Element e:elementsTableau){
        if(e instanceof Spire){
          System.out.println("before : "+((Spire)e).getBatterie());
          ((Spire)e).diminuerBatterie();
          System.out.println("after: "+((Spire)e).getBatterie());
          if(((Spire)e).isAugmentationBatterie()){
            ((Spire)e).augmenterBatterie();
          }
        }
  }
  i =0;
}
```

The diminuerBatterie method does a batterie - -, whereas the augmenterBatterie method does batterie = batterie +10. If it can help, this method is called about 6 times per second.
When I execute it, I get something like this :

```
before: 82.0
after : 81.0
before : 92.0
after : 91.0
before : 81.0
after : 80.0
```

I don't understand why the batterie is decreased, and then, takes back its old value, whereas there are no other methods using this variable.
Thank you for your help

EDIT : Here are the `diminuerBatterie()` and `augmenterBatterie()` methods :

```
public void augmenterBatterie() {
    batterie = batterie+10;
    augmentationBatterie = false;
}

public void diminuerBatterie() {
    if(batterie>0){
        batterie--;
    }
}
```

Comment: show code for the method that increments and decrements `batterie`

Comment: @SJuan76 Yes, I'm using multithreading, but I did not think it could be the cause of my problem, as there is only one thread using the batterie variable (but I may be wrong).

Answer (score 1):

The result seems to be logic, with the way you made your method. It seems you don't work on one instance of the batterie, you start using a for-each loop.

So if we look closer :

- You get the first instance of battery in `elementsTableau`
- you print the value : 82.0
- you decrease, it works then you print the value you have : 81.0
- you increase the value but we don't see if it work because you don't print anything
- then it's the end of the for-each loop so you get the next element in `elementsTableau`
- you probably get an other (different) instance of battery and it's value is : 92.0

So you don't provide the rest of your code but you should ensure you have only one batterie instance in your array (if it still make sense to use an array...) and be sure you always work on this instance of the batterie.

Comment: I completely agree with this answer.

Comment: I should have said it before, but there is only one instance of Spire in elementsTableau(and therefore only one instance of batterie), so I am sure that there is no other batterie.

Comment: @pp0893 So when you enter in `agirBatterie` you only print one time `before: ...` and `after : ...`? You can confirm that? If it's true then the problem is probably in the way you create/fill `elementsTableau`. Again be sure you always use the same instance of `batterie`. If you don't find out yourself try to post the relevant part of your code to be correctly helped.

Comment: @alain.janinm Yes, I tried using a variable inside the "for" loop, I'm sure the if is true only once in the 'agirBatterie' method.

Comment: @pp0893 Ok and what about `elementsTableau`?? Post more code please I can't tell you the problem if I don't know how it's created/filled.